# Python reciprocal type-hinting custom class (definition order issue)

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, python-typing

In python 3.10 I want to define two classes in the same file where one of the methods of each class has to type hint to the other(code follows).

```
class Foo:
    def some_method(arg: Bar):
        return 'Hello'

class Bar:
    def some_method(arg: Foo):
        return 'World'
```

Since one has to be defined first the hint is not allowed since the other type has not yet been defined. How can I solve or go around this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can use quotes to refer the class that have not defined yet like this:

```
class Foo:
    def some_method(self, arg: 'Bar'):
        return 'Hello'

class Bar:
    def some_method(self, arg: Foo):
        return 'World'
```

Comment: Or `annotations` future to limit this ugly syntax to minimal cases, where annotation is a part of a runtime code.